# calling Dialog from property page / sheet

Tags: mfc

I have a property page application. In it, created a dialog called mydlg which is inherited from CDialog.

In the first property page, in its OnInitDialog i tried to launch the mydlg like this:

```
mydlg m;
m.DoModal();
```

but it crashes.

If I move the two lines to the Initinstace in mypropertysheet, it works, the dialog launches. What is the proper way of calling the DoModal in the both places?.

Seconly, how to read the content of edit box on the mydlg from inside the mypropertysheet initinstance using the ID of the edit box.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your code is in the middle of instantiating a property page (which has not yet displayed) and you want to display a modal dialog.  What is the purpose of the dialog that you are trying to display?  Could its processing be encapsulated on the property page?

Answer (score 0):

After DoModal returns the edit box has been destroyed, so you cannot read it using the ID of the edit box. The mydlg class should read the edit box (usually in OnOK) and put the text into a mydlg member variable. After DoModal returns you can still read the mydlg member variable.